# MySQL - Extract only the starting numeric characters from a Text type value

Tags: mysql

In my MySQL database table, I have a column storing text-type values. One of the value is as below:

```
12
abc: 2
bcd_cdm30: 1
ijk_jkl: 2
ijk_mbo: 3
zero_m: 1
single_m: 0
hovered: 2
charged_one: '50'
```

Out of this value, I would like to extract only the first numerical characters, that is 12'. How can I do that in MySQL?

Comment: Select * from table where colname REGEXP '^[0-9]'  Used to find starting digit is a numerical;

Comment: It will start with only a single numeric...

Comment: REGEXP '^[0-9][0-9]' this will result starting with 2 digit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to cast the field to a numeric data type. Mysql will take the leading characters of the value as long as they can be interpreted as a number and discard the rest in the conversion process.

To convert the number to numeric value, just add 0 to it:

```
select text_field + 0 from yourtable
```

Caveat: if you have a really long number there, then it may not fit into any of the numeric data types.